# Unable to make getResourceAsStream() to load the .properties resource - using Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans-8

First of, my sincere apologies for bringing up an oft repeated question in this forum; but I cannot figure out my mistake(s).

I have two .properties files that I am trying to load unsuccessfully. Here's the folder structure I have - unless there is a compelling reason otherwise or it is contrary to the best practice, I like to keep this structure:
[image: Folder Structure]

As you notice my DAO code is under zencs.dbutils package and my .properties files are respectively under zencs.resources.properties.db* packages.

The reason I do it this way because eventually this will connect to and manage multiple data sources - my DAO code will evolve to handle them dynamically (not yet so). I want to set up all data source properties in one place

My Project properties are set as follows:
[image: Project Properties]

Now in my DAO class I have a method initProperties(), called by getConnection(), that is trying to reference these properties files through getResourceAsStream(). Please see below code that I tried:

```
public class DAO {
Connection conn = null;

public Properties properties = new Properties();
public Properties dbConnect = new Properties();

private void initProperties()  {
    InputStream inputDBdrivers = getClass().getResourceAsStream("snowflakeConnect.properties");
    if (inputDBdrivers != null) {
        try{
            dbConnect.load(inputDBdrivers);
            inputDBdrivers.close();
        } catch(IOException ioex) {
            System.err.println(ioex.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("snowflakeConnect.properties file not found! Terminating Application normally...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    InputStream inputDBprops = getClass().getResourceAsStream("snowflake.properties");
    if (inputDBprops != null) {
        try{
            properties.load(inputDBprops);
            inputDBprops.close();
        } catch(IOException ioex) {
            System.err.println(ioex.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("snowflake.properties file not found! Terminating Application normally...");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    // build connection properties
    initProperties();
    try {
        Class.forName(dbConnect.getProperty("driver"));
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
        System.err.println("ERROR: getConnection() :: Snowflake Class not found: " + cnfex.getMessage());
    }

    return DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnect.getProperty("connectStr"), properties);
}

public DAO() {
    try {
      this.conn = getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
      Logger.getLogger(DAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, sqlex);
    }
}
```

}

When I am executing it, the error says "snowflakeConnect.properties file not found! Terminating Application normally..."

My evaluation is that the code in the above form resolving the files to be in zencs/dbutils/ and the ClassLoader cannot find them there obviously.

I tried full absolute path (out of desperation though it expects relative); I tried relative path with "../resources/properties/{dbdrivers | dbutils}/filename.properties" with no success. With the relative path it is resolving to "zencs/dbutils/../resources/properties/dbdrivers/snowflakeConnect.properties" for ClassLoader...

Am I NOT setting the resources folder and everything underneath it correctly?

Obviously my comprehension of how it should resolve is flawed. Can you please help with what I might have not understood and how should I go about this issue?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of Class.getResourceAsStream()? What does it say. Do you find it logical to use a relative path "snowflake.properties" to load a resource file whic is **not** in the same package as the class? How could that possibly work?

Comment: As I mentioned clearly my understanding was flawed but I got it now why it does not work - combination of the debugger, your pointer, and @privoid answer. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use `getResourceAsStream()` including your package name like this:

```
InputStream inputDBdrivers = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/zencs/resources/properties/dbdrivers/snowflakeConnect.properties");
InputStream inputDBprops = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/zencs/resources/properties/dbutils/snowflake.properties");
```

The leading slash is usually the key part here. It could help to remove that as well but you said you've tried that already so I guess that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you @privoid - this worked. I think I now understand what I was doing. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad I could help out, thanks for accepting the answer :)